# I want to find the day difference between 2 date column in azure app insight?

Tags: azure-application-insights

We have a log file where we store the searches happening on our platform. Now there is a departure date and I want to find the searches where departure date is after 330 days from today.

I am trying to run the query to find the difference between departure date column and logtime(entry time of the event into log). But getting the below error:

Query could not be parsed at 'datetime("departureDate")' on line [5,54]

Token: datetime("departureDate")
Line: 5
Position: 54

Date format of departure date is mm/dd/yyyy and logtime format is typical datetime format of app insight.

Query that I am running is below:

```
customEvents
| where name == "SearchLog"
| extend departureDate = tostring(customDimensions.departureDate)
| extend logTime = tostring(customDimensions.logTime)
| where datetime_diff('day',datetime("departureDate"),datetime("logTime")) > 200
```

As suggested I ran the below query but now I am getting 0 results but there is data that satisfy the given criteria.

```
customEvents
| where name == "SearchLog"
| extend departureDate = tostring(customDimensions.departureDate)
| extend logTime = tostring(customDimensions.logTime)
| where datetime_diff('day',todatetime(departureDate),todatetime(logTime)) > 200
```

Example:

departureDate
04/09/2020

logTime

8/13/2019 8:45:39 AM -04:00

I also tried the below query to check whether data format is supported or not and it gave correct response.

```
customEvents
| project datetime_diff('day', datetime('04/30/2020'),datetime('8/13/2019 8:25:51 AM -04:00'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below query. Use `todatetime` statement to convert string to datetime

```
customEvents
| where name == "SearchLog"
| extend departureDate = tostring(customDimensions.departureDate)
| extend logTime = tostring(customDimensions.logTime)
| where datetime_diff('day',todatetime(departureDate),todatetime(logTime)) > 200
```

Comment: As suggested I ran the below query but now I am getting 0 results but there is data that satisfy the given criteria.

Ex:
departureDate logTime 
04/09/2020 8/13/2019 8:45:39 AM -04:00  

I also tried the below query to check whether data format is supported or not and it gave correct response.

    customEvents
    | project datetime_diff('day', datetime('04/30/2020'),datetime('8/13/2019 8:25:51 AM -04:00'))

Answer (score 0):

The double quotes inside datetime operator in where clause should be removed.

Your code should look like:

```
where datetime_diff('day',datetime(departureDate),datetime(logTime)) > 200
```

Comment: tried this but getting the below error:::::::Query could not be parsed at 'datetime(departureDate)'